# Dynamically constructing a binary tree using "Node" structure in python

Tags: python, binary-tree

I’m trying to convert a mathematical expression into a binary tree structure using the “Node” type in zss library. I’m using this particular “Node” type because I want to compute the tree edit distance using a function in the same library.

Mathematical expressions can be in different formats e.g. (28 + 32), (((75 + 2) - 21) + (94 - 90)), ((53 + 67) / 2), ((40 * 51) / (86 - 52)) etc

Trees are binary trees. Root node is always an operator and the leaves are always numbers.

“[Node](http://zhang-shasha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#examples)” tree structure is always **Node(root_node, [leftChild,rightChild])**. Following are few examples of how an expression is represented in a tree.

[image]

Following is what my code currently does ([complete code](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aj9lfQS8qKqwnWiXL_t6pVaPHu0y)):

1. Read in the string expression and split it into tokens
2. Store the indexes of operators in op_index
3. Case 1: when the expression is like (2 + 3) – has one operator (Set the operator as top_operator, Sort the leaf nodes and assign the lowest to the left tree (because of this (2 + 3) and (3 + 2) expressions will always be built into the same manner))
4. Case 2: when the expression is like ((2 + 3) * 5) – has two operators (Set the operator as top_operator and sort the leaf nodes)
5. Return the tree

---

```
def generateTree(bs):
    item = bs.split()
    op_index = []
    top_operator = []
    left_tree = []
    right_tree = []

    # stores the index of each operator in item list
    for i in range(0, len(item)):

        if item[i] in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
            op_index.append(i)


    for n in op_index:

        #case 1
        if (len(op_index) == 1):
            top_operator.append(item[n])
            #a = Node(item[n - 1], [])
            #b = Node(item[n + 1], [])

            if(isLeftChildNodeSmaller(item[n-1], item[n+1]) == True):
                left_tree.append(Node(item[n - 1], []))
                right_tree.append(Node(item[n + 1], []))

            else:
                left_tree.append(Node(item[n + 1], []))
                right_tree.append(Node(item[n - 1], []))

        #case 2
        elif (len(op_index) == 2):

            if(isInt(item[n-1]) == True and isInt(item[n+1]) == True):

                if (isLeftChildNodeSmaller(item[n - 1], item[n + 1]) == True):
                    c = Node(item[n],[Node(item[n - 1], []), Node(item[n + 1], [])])

                else:
                    c = Node(item[n], [Node(item[n + 1], []), Node(item[n - 1], [])])

                right_tree.append(c)

            else:
                top_operator.append(item[n])

                if(isInt(item[n-1]) == True):
                    left_tree.append(Node(item[n-1],[]))
                else:
                    left_tree.append(Node(item[n+1], []))


               right_tree.append(a)



    final_tree = Node(top_operator, [left_tree[0], right_tree[0]])
    return final_tree


    t1 = generateTree("( 2 + 1 )")
    t2 = generateTree("( 5 + ( 2 + 1 ) )")

    editDistance = simple_distance(t1,t2)
    print(editDistance) # returns 2
```

I tried writing the code for two expression types. However I’m trying to figure out a way to write this in a more generic way because when the expressions get more complex it is difficult to build the tree in a static manner.

Comment: I think you want to build the tree recursively.

Comment: @meggar Thank you for the suggestion. I'll try it out.

Comment: did you find a solution to your pb?

Comment: @agenis I could not implement the recursive solutions. So have been using my crude solution. It is for research purposes so I did not have much time to implement a beautiful one.